# PHP mkdir vs chmod

Tags: php, apache, permissões

Estava criando pastas dinamicamente pelo PHP, quando me deparo com a seguinte situação.

#### Ocorrido

Criar um pasta `tmp` com permissão `777` em `/www`

```
mkdir('/www/tmp', intval('0777',8), true);
```

Acontece que ele não fica com permissão 777, mas 755;

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  8 17:51 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  8 17:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  8 17:51 tmp
```

#### Solução

Adicionei o comando `chmod` a ser executado logo em seguida

```
mkdir('/www/tmp', intval('0777',8), true);
chmod('/www/tmp', intval('0777',8));
```

E assim ficou com a permissão desejada `777`.

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  8 17:51 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  8 17:51 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  8 17:51 tmp
```

#### Duvida

- Existe alguma configuração no PHP que limite a permissão que um comando pode dar? Ex.: `mkdir` só poderia usar 444.
- Isso foi algum erro do PHP?

#### Adendo

PHP é baseado em Shell. Em Shell se eu fizer :

```
mkdir /www/tmp;

drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  8 17:51 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  8 17:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  8 17:51 tmp

chmod 0777 /www/tmp;

drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  8 17:51 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  8 17:51 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  8 17:51 tmp
```

Ou seja o PHP poderia estar realizando apenas o `mkdir`? ignorando o segundo parâmetro `intval('0777',8)`?

Comment: Remova o terceiro parâmetro definido como `true` e teste novamente, somente o mkdir(). O intval() também desnecessário. Coloque 0777 sem aspas ou deixe vazio pois o default é 0777.

Comment: Terceiro parâmetro é de recursividade, portanto não é relevante a permissão.

Comment: @DanielOmine o 2º parâmetro deve ser em base octal, seu eu converter uma `string` para octal ou por diretamente um octal, seria a mesma coisa. Quanto ao 3º parâmetro é para deixar as sub-pastas (futuras) com a mesma permissão. Mesmo assim testei como comentaste sem 3º e diretamente `0777` o resultado foi o mesmo. :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parece ser por causa do umask.

Segue tradução da resposta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229353/permissions-with-mkdir-wont-work

Você pode notar que, quando você cria um novo diretório usando este código:

```
mkdir($dir, 0777);
```

A pasta criada realmente possui permissões de 0755, em vez do especificado em 0777. Por que isso? Por causa de `umask()`: http://www.php.net/umask

O valor padrão de umask, pelo menos na minha configuração, é 18. Qual é 22 octal ou 0022. Isso significa que quando você usa `mkdir()` com as permissões 777, o PHP pega 0777 e subtrai o valor atual de umask. No nosso caso 0022, então o resultado é 0755 - o que não é o que você queria, provavelmente.

A "correção" para isso é simples, inclua esta linha:

```
$old_umask = umask(0);
```

Logo antes de criar uma pasta com o `mkdir()` para que o valor real que você coloca seja usado como o CHMOD. Se você quiser retornar umask ao seu valor original quando terminar, use isso:

```
umask($old_umask);
```

Comment: Vou analisar este caso e ja lhe retorno, ja deixo meu +1 pela informação

Comment: Na documentação do `umask` tem uma nota importante que diz, em tradução livre: "Evite utilizar essa função em caso onde o servidor é multithreaded. É melhor mudar a permissão via `chmod` depois de criar o arquivo. Comportamentos inesperados podem ocorrer com scripts concorrentes e com o webserver porque todos eles usam a mesma `umask`"

Answer (score 4):

O modo é modificado pela sua máscara de usuário atual ([umask](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask)), que é `022` neste caso

Você informa a permissão inicial em `mkdir` porém é subtraída a informação de  `umask` para obter a permissão real :

```
  0777
- 0022
======
  0755 = rwxr-xr-x.
```

Se você não quiser que isso aconteça, você precisa configurar seu `umask` temporariamente para zero, portanto não tem mais efeito. Você pode fazer isso com o seguinte trecho.

```
$oldmask = umask(0);
mkdir("test", 0777);
umask($oldmask);
```

A primeira linha muda `umask` para zero enquanto armazena o anterior `$oldmask`. A segunda linha faz o diretório usando as permissões desejadas. A terceira linha restaura o `umask` para o valor original.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997641/why-cant-php-create-a-directory-with-777-permissions)

Documentação: Veja a documentação PHP para [umask](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) e [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mkdir.php) para mais detalhes

Comment: O seu esta mais simples e facil de entender, +1, mas o @DiegoSchmidt já havia dado a resposta, obrigado a colaboração.

Comment: Sim, apenas vi por causa de seu comentário. Mas vou deixar por causa da legibilidade mesmo. Espero ter lhe ajudado.