# Criar diretório (mkdir) com PHP 7.3 no CentOS 7

Tags: php

O comando shell funciona normal via SSH, mas pelo PHP não executa:

```
$cmd = '/bin/bash /usr/local/nginx/html/pHpServer-PG/api/dir.bash';
echo $cmd;
shell_exec($cmd);
```

BASH:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/nginx/html/nome_da_pasta
```

permissões

```
drwxrwxrwx.  8 ec2-user ec2-user  104 May  8 21:56 .
drwxr-xr-x. 12 ec2-user root      183 May  8 12:02 ..
drwxrwxrwx.  4 ec2-user ec2-user 4.0K May  8 21:31 admin
drwxrwxrwx.  4 ec2-user ec2-user 4.0K May  9 01:04 cliente
drwxrwxrwx.  3 ec2-user ec2-user 4.0K May  8 21:31 loja
drwxrwxrwx.  3 ec2-user ec2-user   17 May  8 12:20 pHpServer
drwxrwxrwx.  3 ec2-user ec2-user   17 May  8 12:09 pHpServer-ADm
drwxrwxrwx.  3 ec2-user ec2-user   17 May  8 12:15 pHpServer-PG
```

Obs: estou usando uma instância EC2 da AWS. O log do erro foi esse:

```
mkdir(): Permission denied
```

O usuario do `php-fpm` é o 'nginx'.

Comment: Não é mais simples usar o [`mkdir`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mkdir.php) do PHP?

Comment: Veriica se o usuário que executa o php tem permissão no sudo.

Comment: leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211599/php-mkdir-vs-chmod?rq=1

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss nao conseguir utilizar o mkdir alem de da fatal erro no php-fpm

Comment: @FelipeKusk E não seria interessante entender/resolver o erro fatal?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss so em ultimo caso pq vai da trabalho dmais o servidor e todo modificado com openresty nginx etc so se nao conseguir fazer com bash msm que vou começa a abilitar a log pra começar a procurar

Comment: @David ja tentei todos esse post do stack antes de chegar no bash

Comment: Mas qual é o erro que dá? Isso aí está com muita cara de [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/5878).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ele não executa o bash por via do php, mas pelo ssh funciona mormal

Comment: Mas e o erro que dá ao usar o `mkdir`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss vou abilitar a logs aki pra ver ele da, fatal error no php-fpm, vou analizar aqui e ja volto com o erro

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss aew a log do erro foi a seguinte: mkdir(): Permission denied, o usuario do php-fpm e o 'nginx'

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ae irmao deu, valeu

Comment: Viu? Bem mais fácil que criar um script para isso :D

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss coloque isso como uma resposta :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionei desta forma:

// criar pasta

```
$dir = '/usr/local/openresty/nginx/html/nome_da_pasta';
mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
```

// error log

```
if (!@mkdir($dir)) {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo $error['message'];
}
```

Liberar permisão

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /usr/local/openresty/nginx/html
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para adicionar detalhes. O campo de respostas é para responder a pergunta, não a publicação em si.

Comment: Felipe, se esta foi a solução, queira marcar como resolvido clicando com o "V" verdinho ao lado do post.

Comment: @Bacco só pode ser marcada após 2 dias.

Comment: @Bacco brigado pela correção